# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mb_substr_count()

Tags: php, apache

Ao usar a funcao **mb_substr_count** , é retornado o erro abaixo.
Ja instalei o mb_substr usando o comando -> sudo apt-get install php-mbstring , e reiniciei , mas não resolveu..

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mb_substr_count()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolveu instalando o mbstring via console
sudo apt-get install php7.2-mbstring

Answer (score 1):

Acesse o seu php.ini, pesquise `extension=e` olhe a lista de extensões. Se não houver algum com o nome mbstring, a extensão deverá ser instalada. Se a linha estiver comentada (se tiver `;` na frente), então ela não está ativada ... remova o `;` e reinicie o Apache

Answer (score 1):

Há o comando `php -m` que lista os módulos instalados.

O comando abaixo vai buscar entre os módulos o `mbstring` e retornara algum resultado se ele já estiver sido instalado:

```
php -m | grep mbstring
```

Se não aparecer nenhuma mensagem no terminal, tente instalar com o comando:

```
sudo apt install php-mbstring
```

Após a instalação, reinicie o serviço com o comando:

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```